# yesod init command does not work on Windows

Tags: haskell, yesod

I did the following steps to install the Yesod web framework.

```
mkdir mypackage
cd mypackage
cabal update
cabal sandbox init
cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
```

When I then tried to do `yesod init`, I got an error message.

> 'yesod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I used search to find any yesod-like file but I couldn't find any `yesod.exe` or anything like that. I have searched the entire C: drive.

What happened to the yesod command?

Comment: Any details? What's error?

Comment: 'yesod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did yesod install properly ? Did you see any error messages during the step `cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals` ?

Comment: Are you sure the cabal bin directory is in the path environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

The yesod.exe file should be in `mypackage/.cabal-sandbox/bin/yesod.exe.`. If its not there, try to install yesod-bin again. This directory is not added to the path so the windows command line cannot find yesod.exe. Try this from a command line in the mypackage directory:

```
.cabal-sandbox\bin\yesod init
```

You will have the same problem when you want to run the development server. I solve this on my windows pc by creating a file called devel.bat in the project directory with the following contents:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\.cabal-sandbox\bin
yesod devel
```

Then run the file to start the development server.

Comment: `yesod init` has been disabled.Please use`stack new <project name> <template>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yesod init is disabled and you have to use the stack.Please refer this https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart