# Yesod on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I am trying to run the command yesod init. Obviously from the yesod library in Haskell. I tried to install the library using cabal install alex happy yesod-bin, the library works when running in ghc, but id really like to use the command line program yesod.

I looked here
[yesod init command does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671225/yesod-init-command-does-not-work-on-windows)

But I couldn't actually find any of the files in question. I found the folder with the cabal executable (C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin) it contains alex and happy but not yesod.

The really interesting thing is that I can keep reinstalling yesod-bin (which i can't do with say yesod). I figured this means I should read the cabal configuration file but i really couldn't find it and I am really not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install programs using the default Haskell Platform, the default install location on Windows is

```
C:\Users\SuperAwesomeUser\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
```

Opening a command prompt and typing `cabal install alex happy yesod-bin` successfully installed yesod in this location for me.